# invalid sign error on Okex V5 post request

Tags: python

```
    header = dict()
    header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
    header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = OK_ACCESS_KEY
    header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = self.signature(
        timestamp=OK_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP,
        method=method,
        requestPath=requestPath,
        body=body
    )
    header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(OK_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP)
    header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = OK_ACCESS_PASSPHRASE
    header['x-simulated-trading'] = '0'
```

of course that i have already got signature from timestamp, method, requestPath, body
using hmac sha 256.
Also i have checked GET method and it was fine.

But i received Invalid Sign code: 50113 error duing this process
how can i post request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have to use REST or would you be able to use websockets?

Comment: Here is a post to do it with websockets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874196/how-to-sign-okex-api-v5-login-with-websockets-using-hmac-sha256-encryption-and-b