# How to sign OKEx API V5 login with websockets using HMAC SHA256 encryption and Base64 encoding?

Tags: python, websocket, hmac, sign, hashlib

Although this question has been answered for previous versions of the OKEx API using REST, it hasn't been for the latest version 5 of the API using websockets. The [docs are here](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#websocket-api-login).

I am getting the following error `{"event":"error","msg":"Invalid sign","code":"60007"}` so there must be a problem with the signature string algorithm but I cannot seem to be able to identify where I am making a mistake.

```
import hmac
import json
import time
import hashlib
import asyncio
import websockets

passphrase = "XXXX"
secret_key = b"XXXX"
api_key = "XXXX"

timestamp = int(time.time())
print("timestamp: " + str(timestamp))
sign = str(timestamp) + 'GET' + '/users/self/verify'
total_params = bytes(sign, encoding= 'utf-8')
signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding= 'utf-8'), total_params, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(signature)
print("signature = {0}".format(signature))

async def main():
    msg = \
    {
      "op": "login",
      "args": [
        {
          "apiKey": f'{api_key}',
          "passphrase": f'{passphrase}',
          "timestamp": f'{timestamp}',
          "sign": f'{signature}'
        }
      ]
    }

    async with websockets.connect('wss://wspap.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/private?brokerId=9999') as websocket:
        print(msg)
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The signature needs to be converted back from bytes-string varible into string variable before it is sent.

Adding the following line of code does this: `signature = str(signature, 'utf-8')`

```
import json
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import asyncio
import websockets

passphrase = "XXXX"
secret_key = "XXXX"
api_key = "XXXX"

timestamp = int(time.time())
print("timestamp: " + str(timestamp))
sign = str(timestamp) + 'GET' + '/users/self/verify'
total_params = bytes(sign, encoding= 'utf-8')
signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding= 'utf-8'), total_params, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(signature)
signature = str(signature, 'utf-8')

print("signature = {0}".format(signature))

async def main():
    msg = \
    {
      "op": "login",
      "args": [
        {
          "apiKey": f'{api_key}',
          "passphrase": f'{passphrase}',
          "timestamp": f'{timestamp}',
          "sign": f'{signature}'
        }
      ]
    }

    async with websockets.connect('wss://wspap.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/private?brokerId=9999') as websocket:
        print(msg)
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```