# "Signature for this request is not valid" error when placing a futures order in Binance using the python-binance library

Tags: python, heroku, binance, tradingview-api

I am trying to place a futures order in Binance, using the python-binance library, from a Heroku Server, which is triggered by a webhook in Tradingview. Everything works fine when the webhook is triggered from my local Mac via Insomnia, however if Tradingview triggers the webhook I get a "Signature for this request is not valid error.". The error only occurs when the Heroku server tries to place the order in Binance, as a result of a webhook coming from Tradingview, and not from my local Mac.

```
            order = client_Binance.futures_create_order(
                symbol="BTCUSDT",
                side="BUY",
                type="LIMIT",
                timeInForce="GTC",
                quantity="0.029",
                price="28000.0",
                recvWindow=6000000,
                newClientOrderId = "LongTrd 1C5BTC2L",
                timestamp = 1653043804435
            )
```

I have checked the relationship between server and local time, and there seems to be no problem there, and I have also regenerated API and secret keys multiple times, but nothing seems to work.

I have researched the topic, and I have not found a solution, so I will appreciate very much any help because I have run out of ideas!!!!

Thanks!!

Comment: very strange indeed. I can't think of anything right now but definatelly something to do with the encryption. I also prefer to use `websockets` or `websocket-client` library directly of using an exchange specific library as I feel I have more control over what's going on. It does require some knowledge of `websockets` and `asyncio` but it's "cleaner". It might help you troubleshoot the issue. I haven't done it for binance but here is the code to connect to [okex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71876458/9170226). I'll think some more to see if I come up with an idea to your problem.

Comment: also, have you tried using the `ccxt` library? I prefer to use `websockets` directly but you could try using `ccxt` to troubleshoot your problem and would be easier to implement that coding `websockets` and `asyncio` if you're not familiar with those.

Comment: Thanks for you comments @AlexB, I will explore ccxt library.

Comment: @AlexB: I never found the solution to my problem with the `python-binance` library, however I did use the `ccxt` library as you suggested, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Keep in mind `ccxt` uses REST API so not great if you are making lots of requests for fast arb trading but otherwise it's good enough.